# How to set viewport size in PhantomJS from Chutzpah

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, viewport, qunit, chutzpah

How I can set viewport size in PhantomJS? I tried to set it using `window.callPhantom`:

```
window.callPhantom('page.viewportSize = { width: 480, height: 800 };')
```

as suggested here: https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/issues/355, but this doesn't seem to work, because later `window.innerHeight` still shows 300px (this is the  default height of viewport in PhantomJS)

Comment: Can you include some demonstration ?

Comment: I'm running qunit test in js, via npm test. default browser is phantomjs, so I'm trying to change the viewport size in test setup. Then later when test is executed, I'm checking window.innerHeight and still see 300...

Comment: test case: http://d.pr/n/1akgy

Answer (score 1):

Chutzpah supports you calling phantom to change size but it requires you pass the arguments a little bit differently. Try:

```
window.callPhantom(
{
  Type:"Eval",
  Data: "phantom.pagesize(100,200);"
});
```

I am missing documentation on this which I will correct soon.